# How to define easing option in jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set easing 'easeInCubic' on an animation done using jQuery.

Here my code:

```
$('#content-scroll-inner:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': moveOf}, this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this));
```

Trying something like

```
$('#content-scroll-inner:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': moveOf},'easeInCubic', this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this));
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `easing` option to set easing effect:

```
 easing: 'easeInCubic'
```

This way:

```
 $('#content-scroll-inner:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': moveOf},easing:'easeInCubic', this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this));
```

Comment: copy and pasting your code I get syntax error, could you please double check? thanks

Comment: @GibboK: try using `{duration: "slow",easing: "easein"}`. also have you added the easing library?? http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Answer (score 1):

Use [easing](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)

> Optional. Specifies the speed of the element in different points of
>   the animation. Default value is "swing". Possible values: "swing" -
>   moves slower at the beginning/end, but faster in the middle "linear" -
>   moves in a constant speed Tip: More easing functions are available in
>   external plugins.

With `animate()`:

```
$('#content-scroll-inner:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': moveOf},easing:'easeInCubic', this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this));
```

With `addClass()`

```
$('.foot').addClass('slide-down', 1000, 'easeInCubic');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `easing:` and make sure to add `jquery.ui.js` in your script tag. Please read this [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)